# How to relate a kernel config setting to the source files?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, configuration, source

Here is an example that will explain better:

[image]

I have a selected the audio driver from the picture and i would like to browse through its source. How do i get to the path of the source files from here?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `grep -r CONFIG_SND_SOC_MXS_SGTL5000`.

Each of these config options just represents a `#define` macro. Many of them don't belong to a single file but instead are checked in multiple source files. `CONFIG_64BIT` for example appears in around 1k source code files.

Comment: `grep -r` is generally safer to use since it doesn't follow symlinks (which can create an infinite loop). Also with a self contained directory tree like the kernel, `-R` would search symlinked files multiple times.

Comment: `grep -r CONFIG_SND_SOC_MXS_SGTL5000 ./` For starting from the current directory

Comment: And if you've got many of them to search for, you could use `cscope` for instance to index your source tree first (there's also a nice integration of `cscope` in `vim`).

Comment: It might also control whether a file is even compiled, without appearing inside it.